# KIE Business Central HA - ZK and Helix necessary?

Tags: drools, kie, drools-kie-server, kie-server

In reference to this: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#_wb.vfsclustering
specficially: **If that VFS is located on each local server**, then it must be kept in sync between all servers of a cluster.

Is it possible to avoid the usage of ZK and Helix to coordinate multiple business central servers when a shared PVC (volume mount) in k8s is used.
Say the shared volume was mounted at /opt/jboss/vfs
and the following config was set:
org.uberfire.nio.git.dir /opt/jboss/vfs
org.guvnor.m2repo.dir /opt/jboss/vfs/m2

Does this allow multiple instances to share editor file locks and everything else that needs to be coordinated?

Comment: Any update on this as I am also thinking in same direction?

Comment: I never made it beyond a single instance poc. My guess is that the service probably uses helix for mutual exclusion in some ways that can't be achieved with just a git repo.